# Converting existing dynamic website to an android app using phonegap

Tags: android, mysql, angularjs, cordova

I've a dynamic website which uses HTML5 and AngularJS as front end and REST api. And I have setup the phonegap in my windows 7 PC as well. My Question is what are the steps that I've to follow in order to create an android APK file out of the existing files. There are lot of tutorials on creating new phonegap project from the scratch. But I couldn't find any help on importing existing static website to phonegap project.

Comment: Just follow the steps of any tutorial, and then swap the tutorial website code for your own. You usually just need to put your files in a www-folder in the Phonegap project.

Comment: And what about the database?

Comment: Oh, you wrote about help on importing a static website. Just make sure your webpage communicates with your database. You will however not be able to run php-code on phonegap. So my guess is that it would be much simpler for you to create a webbapp-version of your site and then wrap that in a webview in phonegap.

Comment: But I need to use the category list option of android window for my website categories.?

Comment: Then what you need is an app that will wrap your homepage in a webview.